# Why is Android WebView sending a 'beforeunload' event when it isn't unloading?

Tags: cordova, webview

My app, which is Cordova based, listens for 'beforeunload' in order to perform some cleanup and to put the app into an exiting state, whereby it will not attempt certain things that are likely to not complete (e.g. database updates).

The problem is that recently (4 customers have reported issues related to this over the past month, for an app that has not changed in 12 months, has been working fine for many years) my app is being sent 'beforeunload' event after being in background for say 5 mins, but it then doesn't actually unload.

So the app is left running, but in a state where it thinks it is exiting, which is causing all sorts of issues.

I have a couple of couple of fixes ready to ship. One is to ignore the unload event, which as the app generally stays running in background these days, not entering an exiting state is probably not a big deal.

Another is to switch to use 'unload' event rather than 'beforeunload' which I have yet to test out properly but may be a more appropriate option.

My question is really, is this odd behaviour of 'beforeunload' to be expected/known or is it a bug in webview?

My use of beforeunload goes back 4 or 5 years, so it may well be outdated and need a review.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Some Android phones with 'security/battery policies' that, suspend the app in background after a few minutes.

Comment: I can understand the suspending, and that's why I am handling `beforeunload`, what I don't understand is why recently, these clients are being sent `beforeunload` but not then actually unloading (as though `beforeunload` had done `preventDefault()` and cancelled the unload - which it hasn't), that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use cordova pause and resume events to prevent beforeunload logic execution when app is in the background.

Comment: because I need to run in background, so only want to do exit cleanup on actual exit hence using beforeunload

Comment: what you just said exactly fits the solution I proposed. A real exit will probably not happen when running in background or if it happens in background you care less of visually clean exit. Thus use cordova pause and resume events to detect when you are in the background and in such case don't run beforeunload logic.

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer. As mentioned in the question, that is already one of the proposed workarounds.